# Constant kernel panics (arch and gentoo)

Tags: arch-linux, gentoo, kernel-panic

For the past few months, my Linux installation have been kernel panicking every couple of hours or so.It didn't bother me much back then since I had Windows on another drive which I ended up using 24/7 due to constant crashed on Linux.

I was using Arch Linux when it first started, at around kernel version 5.11 to 5.12 I don't remember exactly. A few frustrating weeks later I switched to Gentoo Linux but it got worse with kernel panics being more frequent. I switched back to Arch Linux a few months later, it still kernel panics but not as often.

I don't have the system logs from the first Arch install but I do remember it was mainly caused by Firefox or Discord. I do have some logs from Gentoo, and from what little I could tell it's usually Discord crashing, segfaults and kernel NULL pointer dereference. On my current Arch install it's a lot of dumped core on firefox and a kernel crash I can't understand.

I never used to have any crashes before 5.10, I don't know if something changed in firefox, discord or the kernel that's causing these crashes or if my hardware is faulty which I doubt since Windows worked perfectly fine all along. I always used the latest, bleeding edge kernel on both Gentoo and Arch. I tried out Zen kernel once on Gentoo but got the same result. Is there some kind of setting on firefox that might fix this or should I try a different kernel from the AUR like linux-hardened, linux-lts or linux-zen?

EDIT:
While I was typing this, everything went nuts. From what I can tell it's a this piece of error spammed every 0.001 second creating a log file that's about 1.6 GB. What?

```
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: list_add corruption. next->prev should be prev (ffff9c51dea737a8), but was ffff9c4f09ab80a8. (next=ffff9c51dea737a8).
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: WARNING: CPU: 9 PID: 0 at lib/list_debug.c:23 __list_add_valid+0x38/0x70
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: Modules linked in: cfg80211 8021q garp mrp stp llc nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common eeepc_wmi asus_wmi ucsi_ccg snd_hda_codec_realtek sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_generic typec_ucsi uvcvideo edac_mce_amd ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi platform_profile typec rfkill videobuf2_vmalloc kvm_amd snd_hda_intel roles video wmi_bmof mxm_wmi videobuf2_memops asus_wmi_sensors snd_intel_dspcfg videobuf2_v4l2 kvm snd_usb_audio snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_usbmidi_lib irqbypass snd_hda_core snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common rapl snd_hwdep snd_seq_device videodev snd_pcm joydev mousedev snd_timer mc sp5100_tco pcspkr igb snd soundcore gpio_amdpt k10temp mac_hid i2c_piix4 gpio_generic i2c_nvidia_gpu dca pinctrl_amd wmi acpi_cpufreq fuse bpf_preload ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 dm_crypt cbc encrypted_keys trusted asn1_encoder tee tpm dm_mod usbhid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd nvme ccp cryptd nvme_core xhci_pci rng_core xhci_pci_renesas
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: CPU: 9 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/9 Tainted: P        W  OE     5.18.6-arch1-1 #1 c9877892a63ec275868771a7abba7cb50c474f8e
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/ROG STRIX X470-F GAMING, BIOS 5809 12/03/2020
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: RIP: 0010:__list_add_valid+0x38/0x70
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: Code: 75 19 4c 8b 02 49 39 c0 75 26 48 39 fa 74 3a 49 39 f8 74 35 b8 01 00 00 00 c3 cc 48 89 c1 48 c7 c7 38 ba f1 ad e8 64 3b 60 00 <0f> 0b 31 c0 c3 cc 48 89 d1 48 89 c6 4c 89 c2 48 c7 c7 88 ba f1 ad
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffc1e3801b7e40 EFLAGS: 00010082
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9c4ef69d00a8 RCX: 0000000000000027
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: RDX: ffff9c51dea616a8 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9c51dea616a0
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: RBP: ffff9c51dea72cc0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffc1e3801b7c50
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: R10: 0000000000000003 R11: ffff9c51ef32bc28 R12: ffff9c51dea737a8
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: R13: ffff9c51dea737a8 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff9c4ef69d0000
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9c51dea40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: CR2: 00007efca6ae3000 CR3: 0000000133d0c000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: Call Trace:
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  <TASK>
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  pick_next_task_fair+0x177/0x3d0
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  __schedule+0x17f/0x11f0
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  ? recalibrate_cpu_khz+0x10/0x10
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  ? tick_nohz_idle_exit+0xe1/0x130
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  schedule_idle+0x2a/0x40
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  cpu_startup_entry+0x1d/0x20
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  start_secondary+0x11c/0x140
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xd5/0xdb
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel:  </TASK>
Jun 27 23:46:02 archlinux kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

Worst thing about these crashes is that I can't even shutdown my pc by holding down the power button. Like the whole system on a hardware level is completely frozen. I literally need to switch off the power supply to turn it off.

Hardware: Ryzen 5 3600X, 16GB RAM, GTX 1660 Ti, M.2 SSD for linux, hard drive for windows.

Other system logs:

I'ĺl just dump the entire logs into a google drive before everything crashes again.

arch logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jpF9qr8cmp6dL1zW3pedfpdfWqV6nUxu/view?usp=sharing

gentoo logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fwC5rk_WMt9shWpGsLP8yMDLHQEhTVAO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should try an extended memory test first.

Comment: Also, are you overclocking your machine?   Are your memory timings set correctly in the BIOS? and what version of the nvidia driver are you running (and is it the packaged version for your distro(s) or installed by downloading from nvidia's own site)?  Is firefox/chromium (or Discord which is chromium in drag) configured to use GPU acceleration?   Do you notice any particular patterns to the crashes - i.e. things you are doing, programs you're running, when you're using WIFI, etc. Do you generally have lots of free RAM or are you constantly swapping?

Comment: Bad RAM, bad memory timings, overclocking. Your error probably indicates memory is faulty: *list_add corruption. next->prev should be prev (ffff9c51dea737a8), but was ffff9c4f09ab80a8. (next=ffff9c51dea737a8)* Please run https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm for at least a couple of hours

Comment: Hello, everything regarding BIOS settings are default, firefox settings too. No overclocking, I use the latest precompiled drivers, kernel, etc that's currently on AUR and emerge (~amd64 on gentoo, firefox-bin and genkernel to compile the kernel). Older logs indicated it was firefox and discord but now it's more of the kernel crashing or something. I do agree it looks like a memory corruption or bad RAM from the lastest logs, I don't get how Windows was working perfectly fine without any issues? Should I do a memtest?

Comment: Definitely do a memtest, it's been recommended at least twice in the comments so far.

Comment: *I don't get how Windows was working perfectly fine without any issues?* Linux and Windows have wildly different kernel/user (spaces), so the Linux kernel might be using part of the memory which Windows barely or ever touches. For the same reason I've seen PCs with bad memory which BSOD under Windows and which are stable under Linux. People blame Windows, while the culprit is their hardware. *Should I do a memtest?* I've even posted the link, darn.

Comment: One other thing worth trying is to remove and re-insert all your RAM and PCI-e devices (including GPU and any NVME drives), to make sure they are all properly installed with good connections.  It's surprising how often a not-quite-perfectly installed DIMM can cause memory problems.  This is especially common in machines that get moved around a lot, little bumps from being in a car can slightly dislodge parts.  Check that all your power and sata and other connectors are securely installed too.

Comment: And take the opportunity to clean the PC too - a small artist's paint-brush and mini vacuum cleaner are good for removing dust.  A Ryzen 3600X is still a very good CPU, but it is several years old now.  As is your X470 motherboard.  It's probably overdue for a clean and service.  Also check to see if there are any BIOS updates for your m/b - the kernel dump says it's running `BIOS 5809 12/03/2020` - windows drivers tend to have manufacturer specific workarounds for buggy AGESA data, while linux drivers tend to accept that data at face-value. A BIOS upgrade can help a lot.

Comment: Hello again, I´ve done a memtest, memory checks out fine. Here are the results: https://imgur.com/a/SwJkZNE I then upgraded my bios to version 6042. It looks like my BIOS was so unbelievably outdated, like 10 updates behind from 2020. It reset the BIOS settings and I noticed there were no more errors which I usually saw during boot up. So far so good, Iĺl test it out for the next day and let you know if it has stabilized or still crashes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello @cas it looks like the BIOS update helped a lot! Iḿ no longer getting any kernel panics. There are a few dumped core from Isolated Web Co (module firefox) and Discord and a single BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000. However it didn´t cause the whole system to crash so I just had to logout and login to fix Discord not responding. Iḿ kind of curious now, how can an outdated BIOS cause such massive kernel panics and crashes? Isn´t the BIOS supposed to check the hardware, boot order and hand over control to the kernel?

Comment: The BIOS (which includes [AGESA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGESA) microcode on AM4 and some other platforms) initialises the hardware on power-up/reboot.  Like all code, AGESA can have bugs and like all code those bugs often get fixed with new releases (and/or new bugs introduced).  One of the ways that the Linux kernel finds out what hardware is on the system and how it is set up is by querying the BIOS.  If the BIOS either set up, say the memory timings, incorrectly or gave Linux incorrect data about the H/W, that can cause problems.

Comment: HW stuff is mostly off-topic for U&L, so I suggest you google "AGESA Linux" (and similar/related searches). I found a simple but reasonable overview of AGESA at https://itigic.com/what-is-amd-agesa/ and another about the AM4 boot process at https://www.igorslab.de/en/inside-amd-bios-what-is-really-hidden-behind-agesa-the-psp-platform-security-processor-and-the-numbers-of-combo-pi/ and notes about availability of the latest AGESA 1207 at https://www.tomshardware.com/news/agesa-1207-am4-motherboard-roundup. BTW, you can post an Answer saying what you did to solve the problem and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the BIOS helped a lot.